# while training model with AgglomerativeClustering algorithm getting memory error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I am training one model for unsupervised learning. Data set has 1,40,000 rows and 6 columns. file size is 10,637 KB of csv type.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
```

above libraries imported.

```
Rev =  pd.read_csv(r"Updated_Rev.csv")
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder.fit(Rev["Technology"])
Rev["Technology"] = labelEncoder.transform(Rev["Technology"])
```

one column is string so encoded it but not used in training may be require in future.

```
train = Rev.iloc[:,:4]
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering()
clustering.fit(train)
```

this is train file so all rows are required for training and chose 4 columns out of them.
while doing this got this error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 67.9 GiB for an array with shape (9117833280,) and data type float64
```

#### point to be noted

1. I do not have admin access of system.
2. It is windows OS and using Anaconda's base environment.
3. Anaconda is installed for specific user only.

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0f4f354e9aaf> in <module>
      1 train = Rev.iloc[:,:4]
----> 2 clustering.fit(train)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_agglomerative.py in fit(self, X, y)
    857                                          n_clusters=n_clusters,
    858                                          return_distance=return_distance,
--> 859                                          **kwargs)
    860         (self.children_,
    861          self.n_connected_components_,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_agglomerative.py in ward_tree(X, connectivity, n_clusters, return_distance)
    232                           stacklevel=2)
    233         X = np.require(X, requirements="W")
--> 234         out = hierarchy.ward(X)
    235         children_ = out[:, :2].astype(np.intp)
    236 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py in ward(y)
    828 
    829     """
--> 830     return linkage(y, method='ward', metric='euclidean')
    831 
    832 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py in linkage(y, method, metric, optimal_ordering)
   1054                          'matrix looks suspiciously like an uncondensed '
   1055                          'distance matrix')
-> 1056         y = distance.pdist(y, metric)
   1057     else:
   1058         raise ValueError("`y` must be 1 or 2 dimensional.")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in pdist(X, metric, *args, **kwargs)
   2002     out = kwargs.pop("out", None)
   2003     if out is None:
-> 2004         dm = np.empty((m * (m - 1)) // 2, dtype=np.double)
   2005     else:
   2006         if out.shape != (m * (m - 1) // 2,):

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 67.9 GiB for an array with shape (9117833280,) and data type float64
```

Comment: You might not be able to work with huge dataset, see this for more details [Link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/how-to-run-agglomerativeclustering-on-a-big-data-in-python)

Comment: thanks manojk. **how I can train model using 10k records  and save model ->repeat till the end of record**. I have been searching for this approch.

Comment: Even I am not sure about it, google for some batch-wise training in clustering or post a new question on datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Batch wise training won't change any  accuracy. It is working same as normal k means algorithm. It don't have any problem for training whole dataset

Comment: Then see if there is already a post on datascience.stackexchange.com if not then create, this site (SO) is more for a programming perspective, data science site will definitely have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Large Data is not supported by Agglomerative Clustering

By definition, the algorithm needs O(n²) memory and O(n³) runtime.

**Sample the data OR use different algorithm**

Link :
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/how-to-run-agglomerativeclustering-on-a-big-data-in-python